# Get pivot tables on bin in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like below.

```
data1 = 

index  A_bin  B_bin  C_bin  D_bin  Decider 
0      4      3      2      1      0
1      2      1      2      1      1
2      5      2      1      2      1
3      1      3      5      1      0
4      1      3      3      2      0
5      5      1      2      1      1
6      3      2      4      1      0
```

I want to create two dataframes that gives the count of `'Decider'=0` and `'Decider'=1` for each bin and each column in data1.

Again `B_bins` and `D_bins` do not have 5 bins each, so the missing bins will count 0 for them.

the final dataframes that I want looks like below..

```
final_data1 = (giving the count of 'Decider'=0)

bins  A_0   B_0   C_0   D_0     
1     2     0     0     3
2     0     1     1     1
3     1     3     1     0
4     1     0     1     0
5     0     0     1     0
```

final_data2 = (giving the count of 'Decider'=1)

```
bins  A_1   B_1   C_1   D_1     
1     0     2     1     2
2     1     1     2     1
3     0     0     0     0
4     0     0     0     0
5     2     0     0     0
```

And in the real dataset, I have more than 300 columns and bins in the range of 1 to 10 with 'Decider' as the last column. So any code expressed by the column name will be a bit difficult task.

How to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary after grouping on `Decider` and iterating over them after unpivoting them using `melt` , then use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for counts and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for missing indexes  , then just access each key of the dictionary for the final dataframes:

```
m = df.melt('Decider',value_name='bins')
d ={f"df_{i}" : pd.crosstab(g['bins'],g['variable']).reindex(sorted(m['bins'].unique())
         ,fill_value=0).add_suffix(f"_{i}").rename_axis(None,axis=1)
                                    for i,g in m.groupby('Decider')}
print(d)
```

---

```
print(d['df_0'],'\n\n',d['df_1'])
```

---

```
      A_bin_0  B_bin_0  C_bin_0  D_bin_0
bins                                    
1           2        0        0        3
2           0        1        1        1
3           1        3        1        0
4           1        0        1        0
5           0        0        1        0 

       A_bin_1  B_bin_1  C_bin_1  D_bin_1
bins                                    
1           0        2        1        2
2           1        1        2        1
3           0        0        0        0
4           0        0        0        0
5           2        0        0        0
```